# How to synthesize UDP (User defined primitive) for fpga

Tags: fpga

I am a newbie with fpga design. I am trying to synthesize a udp file for fpga prototyping.
Currently, Vivado and synplify cannot support synthesis for UDP file.
Anybody have the solution, please help me !
I intend to create a model for UDP with verilog.
Is this solution okay or not ?
Thanks in advance !

Trong

Comment: see [SO udp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244933/synth-8-27-primitives-not-supported-in-vivado)